# How to model a roll against a "difficulty roll" in AnyDice?

Tags: anydice

I'm working on a custom ttrpg system and I've noticed a lot of answers to questions in here regarding AnyDice. You would roll two die (such as a d6 and a d8) against a third die of any size up to a d12. The third die determines difficulty. Having at least 1 die meet or exceed the difficulty is a minor success, while both meeting or exceeding is a major success. Any help on how to set this up would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main trick you need here is to make two comparisons to a single row. The way to do this is to cast it to a function. Then we just get to treat our variables as an outcome of a roll, not dice.

We then just compare the result each of the two dice with the result of the target die. Resulting the sum means 1 means a minor success and 2 a major.

```
function: roll A:n B:n against T:n {
  result: (A>=T)+(B>=T)
}

output [roll 1d8 1d6 against d12]
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that the `A:n B:n` part of the definition causes each of the first two rolls to be summed into a single number even if there's more than one die in each rolled pool. If you defined the function using `A:s B:s`, the rolls would be converted into sequences instead, which would let you do e.g. `[roll 2d8 3d6 against d12]` and get a count ranging from zero to 2 + 3 = 5 of all the dice in 2d8 and 3d6 meeting or exceeding the random d12 target.